# Superfluous Error correction

Tags: exam-questions, error

> Doctor Alex (A) /was an educated(B) /man of letters (C)/ no error (D)

The above question was asked in my exam in which I was asked to mark the error in the given sentence from four options (A,B,C,D). I know the error, it's that educated here is superfluous with man of letters as man of letters itself means educated but I am confused whether to mark the answer as B or C as the sentence can be corrected by two ways **Doctor Alex was an educated man** or **Doctor Alex was a man of letters**. That is it can be corrected by both ways (either by correcting B part or C part of given sentence.) What answer should I mark in exam?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure of your answer?
I think it's **D** - no errors
It looks to me like the section that is selected is dropped resulting in

> Doctor Alex was an educated man of letters.

Are you sure "educated" and "man of letters" are the same?
Certainly a "man of letters" is "educated", but are they so similar as to be redundant?

> [**Man of letters**, a term used to describe **certain types** of intellectual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_of_letters)

Comment: Man of letters includes "educated" itself in its meaning , that is   if a person is said to be man of letters its obvious that he is educated too   so certainly using educated and man of letters contemporarily  is superfluous.

Comment: Not necessarily, user. As explained in this other question, "letters" is an archaic way to refer to literature. A man of letters may not have received a formal education, or he may have received a science-based education but also enjoys literature. I also vote for D. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29239/to-what-do-the-letters-in-the-title-a-man-of-letters-refer

Comment: We need the exact instructions for this question, it seems to me  if you get rid of the **B** section, you lose your "was" verb; (**C**) doesn't have a verb; and (**D**) doesn't belong there; and the instructions should be clear about what to remove. Let's not make the schoolboy error of *assuming* on a test question...usually test questions need to be processed in a particular way.